# Get Maximum and Minimum value from rrd file generated by Cacti

Tags: centos, rrdtool, rrd, cacti

I have an rrd file in which traffic_in and out stats of interfaces are stored.

What i want is that i want Max and min values in certain time period.

I'm trying this command but it is giving me error ERROR: invalid rpn expression in: v,MAX

```
rrdtool graph -s 1537466100 -e 1537552237 DEF:v=lhr-spndc-7609_traffic_in_612.rrd:traffic_in:MAX CDEF:vm=v,MAX PRINT:vm:%lf
```

Can you please help to enter correct command & achieving desired Functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using VDEF for the definition of `vm`, not CDEF.

A CDEF is for transforming one or more data *series* created by either a DEF or CDEF into another *series*, ready for graphing or summarising.

A VDEF is for transforming a single data series into a single value via a consolodation function, such as to get the maximum value of a series over the entire graph.  This is different from the function specified in a DEF, which only specifies how to consolodate a higher-granularity series into a lower-granularity series.

Comment: Hello dear i have tried with VDEF as well. Can you tell me what is the solution then.

Comment: DEF:v=file.rrd:ds:MAX VDEF:vm=v,MAXIMUM -- this gives you the single value for maximum of ds over the entire time window.  Similarly with MIN/MINIMUM to get minimum values, provided you have the necessary RRAs in the file.

Comment: i'm getting this error Mr.Steve "ERROR: Not a valid vname: v in line VDEF:vm=v,MAXIMUM"

Comment: This means you have not configured v correctly.  Check the rest of your commandline and look for other errors.  Make sure you define v before using it to define vm.